# how to save user entered dynamic input in Shiny data.frame - no. of input changes per user and so does dataframe

Tags: r, dynamic, dataframe, shiny

I have a program where I ask user to enter Asset Name and the Weight (% owned) of the asset. It is dynamic i.e. one user can have 3 assets, another can have 20 assets. So the data.frame used to save the inputs has to be dynamic too.
I am trying to figure out how I can save the data in this - dynamic - way. I tried using matrixInput using the shiny_incubator package but doesn't work all that well for me especially because it's a matrix and I am trying to store a data.frame (numeric + strings in my inputs).

below is the code to enter inputs based on total number of assets the user holds in his portfolio. Disclaimar -  **treysp** helped me write this.

server.UI

```
 shinyServer( function(input, output, session) {

   output$tickers <- renderUI({
       numAssets <- as.integer(input$assets)

         lapply(1:numAssets, function(i) {
          list(tags$p(tags$u(h4(paste0("Asset ", i)))),
          textInput(paste0("ticker", i), label = "Ticker Name", value = "Enter ticker..."),
         numericInput(paste0("weight", i), label = "Weight of Asset", value=0))  
                                })
                          })
                                               })
```